# Changing the value of a variable in an array using bash

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I am trying to create a simple way of initializing a group of variables.

The thought was to create an array and add the variables to the array, then loop through them and initialize them.

The problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to change the value of a variable in an array. I know how to change `FruitsArray[3]` to equal something else, but if variable `$Apple` is in the array and I want to change it from "safe" to "poisoned" I cannot seem to figure it out.

Of course, there might be an easier way to initialize a group of variables, but it seems like I should know how to do this and am missing something obvious.

Comment: `FruitsArray[$Apple]=poisoned`

Comment: What do you mean by "variable `$Apple` is in the array". An array doesn't contain other variables.

Comment: `$Apple` will be the value of the variable `Apple` which is in the array.  You  just need to change the value in the corresponding index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have this:

```
FruitsArray[0]="Apricot"
FruitsArray[1]="Avocado"
FruitsArray[2]="Banana"
FruitsArray[3]="Apple"
```

And, also:

```
Apple="safe"
```

And you want to change the value of Apple which is pointed by FruitsArray[3].

Accesing such a value is called *indirection*:

```
index="${FruitsArray[3]}"
echo "variable and value ${FruitsArray[3]}=${!index}"
```

And is changed with:

```
declare ${FruitsArray[3]}="poisoned"
```

Whole script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FruitsArray[0]="Apricot"
FruitsArray[1]="Avocado"
FruitsArray[2]="Banana"
FruitsArray[3]="Apple"

Apple="safe"

index="${FruitsArray[3]}"
echo "from ${FruitsArray[3]}=${!index}"
declare ${FruitsArray[3]}="poisoned"
echo "to ${FruitsArray[3]}=${!index}"
```

On execution:

```
from Apple=safe
to Apple=poisoned
```